# Entering form data from a post method in php

Tags: php, sql, post

I have a database with primary key set to auto increment. I can't enter form data from a post method in php.

Here's the code. I have logins table in users database. Also a form whose action is set to below code.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
    if (isset($_POST['Full-name']) && isset($_POST['psd']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
            $link2 = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Oops! Can't connect");
            @mysqli_select_db($link2, 'users') or die("Can't find Database");
            $fullname = $_POST['Full-name'];
            $email2 = $_POST['email'];
            $newpassword = $_POST['psd'];
            echo $fullname.$email2.$newpassword; //print sucessfully

            $query2 = mysqli_query($link2, "INSERT INTO logins VALUES (NULL, $email2, $newpassword)");
            if ($query2) {
    echo "You have signed up successfully";
} else {

    echo "Error: ";   //query prints this statement
}
mysqli_close($link2);
        }   

}

?>
```

Here's my database Structure [Db structure](http://postimg.org/image/to7acuozf)

Comment: Please show your database table structure. Also, what are $email2 and $newpassword? Please show your entire code.

Comment: Ok, now its visible. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: which field is set as Null

Comment: And what does your database table look like?

Comment: Here's my database https://postimg.org/image/to7acuozf/

Comment: @AroshaMudalige. Could you try my method and let me know what happens. And i shall provide you with a solution.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P Problem solved. Thanks a ton. I entered $query = "INSERT INTO logins(username,password) VALUES ('".$email2."', '".$newpassword."')";
   $query2 = mysqli_query($link2, $query); in the code and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @AroshaMudalige. Glad to help you. :)

Comment: You just implemented an SQL-injection vulnerable code. Congratulations!

Comment: @MikeSzyndel That's what was on the tutorial I refered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  have to first remember that you have provide only **10 Character for username** and **8 characters for password**.

Even though if it is a varchar it will allow only 10 Charterers for Username and 8 Characters for Password and above that if you enter i am damp sure it will show you error wile inserting into the database.

Ensure updating or changing of the values that you provide for username and password in the database.

> **Note:** By Chance if the user provided 11 Character for username and 8 Character for password too it will not be entering into the DB.

**Cross Check:** Try putting echo to the statement  and exit the loop after that and you directly put the echoed query in MYSQL so that you can find the Error very Easy and rectify it as per the requirement you need.

And your query need to altered like this considering the `id` as auto-increment.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($link2, "INSERT INTO logins(`username,password`) VALUES ('".$email2."', '".$newpassword."')");
```

Problem wasn't in the number of characters. But it was in the query.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($link2, "INSERT INTO logins(`username,password`) VALUES ('".$email2."', '".$newpassword."')");
```

didn't worked. But replacing it with,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO logins(username,password) VALUES ('".$email2."', '".$newpassword."')";
$query2 = mysqli_query($link2, $query);
```

worked for me! Thanks everyone who replied.

Comment: @Arosha Mudalige . You pls echo the statement and then put it into the database and you check once. You will find the Error what it is.

Comment: I chaged the $query2 to what you said. But still shows "Error: ". And by echoing did you mean echo $query2;? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yes. you echo the statement like this above the line where you have applied mysqli_query.

Comment: Put echo : $query = "INSERT INTO logins(`username,password`) VALUES ('".$email2."', '".$newpassword."')" for this above the mysqli_query line and place exit after that.

Comment: If you put echo and exit the query alone will be displayed and the execution will be stopped after that if you place `exit` keyword so that you can copy the echoed query and place it in the SQL section of the DB and check .

Comment: Under $query2 = mysqli_qu.... statement I entered echo $query2;. But it doesn't get executed. So after my query it jumps to else part and print "Error: "

Comment: Yes I did it and it showed  ''MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0415 sec)''. When I checked the database data was entered. But in web interface it prints "Error: "

Comment: @AroshaMudalige. Glad to help you . If you find my answer need to be improved you can upgrade my answer too so that some more better research will be done in oder to generate more closer output so that it will be useful for the other developers who get the same Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Insert into logins (Id,email,password) values (NULL, ....
```

Assuming your names fields are "Id", "email", "password", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if Null value is for you id (auto-increment) then you don't want to specify it leave it blank. just like  this

```
 $query2 = mysqli_query($link2, "INSERT INTO logins(username,password) VALUES ($email2, $newpassword)");
```

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It says "Error: ". This is the output when 'if ($query2)' is false.

Comment: Code runs successfully until $query2 is assigned. I checked.

Comment: please check your db whether data is inserted

Comment: I checked, but data hasn't inserted.